# Data not showing in Crystal reports

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm using a **ConnectionString** located at a Module for all of my Code in the project.
Code:

```
Public connString As String = "Data Source=192.168.1.11,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=MY_DB;User Id=sa;Password = abc@1234
```

But for the Crystal Reports, I have added a project **Data Source** using project > add new Data Source > New Connection and used a ConnectionString.

After adding, I can see the **Table and Fields**. Once I add this to a Report, and browse Data through Field explorer, I don't see any Data. When I add the fields to a report, same happens. But, in the actual Table there are Rows.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is your Provider ?

Comment: Have you tried showing the SQL query in your Crystal Report so you can copy and paste it into a query tool to see if it returns data?  This will allow you to confirm if the problem is related to how you built the query in Crystal Report.  If the query does not return any data rows, then you likely have a bad link between your tables.